# Dummy dependent on value in past observation

Tags: r, dataframe, dummy-variable

I am trying to create a dummy for when income is below 450.000 in period 1 for each individual ID.
What I have tried, without success is this:

```
data$ABOVE <-  ifelse(data$INCOME >= 450000, 0, 1)
```

The problem with that code is that it only depends on whether the income in the current observation is above 450000 or below. I need it to be dependent on TIME 1 for each ID in case some individuals in the entire dataset have income below in one observation, and below in another.

This is my data:

```
structure(list(ID = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2), TIME = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 
2, 3), GROUP = c(2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1), INCOME = c(419295.47, 428499.91, 
403197.03, 1286735.3, 1390325.1, 1359411), HIGH = c(0, 0, 0, 
1, 1, 1)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

With `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
data %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(ABOVE = ifelse(first(INCOME) >= 450000, 0, 1)) %>%
  ungroup()
```

I've kept your `ifelse` statement as-is from the question, but it does seem backward to me--I would think `ABOVE = 1` should mean the value was above 450000, but you have the 0 and 1 switched.

Comment: Yes, I see that I have mixed that up. Changed it now. Thank you very much!